# replace image name from array

Tags: javascript, html

I have a page that displays 6 rows containig 3 images each. Each image is enlarged onmouseover. The page is showing a list of "events" thefore it will grow in the future and and each new event will be the first of the list.

I think that it would be more practical if I could replace the names of the images with generic ones (image1,image1_small...) and have an array that assigns the right names to the images.
something like this:

```
var imm1 = "ragaini2016_small.jpg";
var imm2 = "ragaini2016.jpg";
var imm3 = "possenti2016_small.jpg";
var imm4 = "possenti2016.jpg";  
......
```

But I don't know how to write the code inside the `<img src="xxx" ....`

Here below the html code of one of the rows:

```
<div class="row" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto; width=100%">
        <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:transparent;padding-top:1%;" >
        <p style="background-color:transparent;text-align:center;color:white;font-weight:bold;">7 Maggio 2016</p>
   <div class="ienlarger" style="margin: 0 auto; display:table;" >
```

21 Aprile 2016

19 Marzo 2016

thank you
gabriele

Comment: Did you try any JavaScript?

Comment: I'm unable to write a javascript to do what I want. It is the reason why I asked for help !

Comment: The idea is you show an effort, though. People are unlikely to do the work for you, but if you show an attempt, people will help. Sounds like you need some tutorials.

Comment: Could you please suggest where I could find a tutorial for this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small snippet to add an array of images to HTML. I'm pretty sure this isn't exactly what you need, but here's a start.

```js
let arr = ['image1.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image2.jpg', 'image3.jpg', 'image4.jpg', 'image5.jpg', 'image6.jpg'],
  imageTags = [], divElt = document.getElementById('ienlarger');
arr.forEach(function(item, index) {
  img = document.createElement("img");
  img.src = item;
  divElt.appendChild(img);
});
```

```html
<div class="row" style="margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto; width=100%">
  <div class="col-md-4" style="background-color:transparent;padding-top:1%;">
    <p style="background-color:transparent;text-align:center;color:white;font-weight:bold;">7 Maggio 2016</p>
    <div id="ienlarger" class="ienlarger" style="margin: 0 auto; display:table;"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are the required steps:

Create a container html div element and give an id to it, lets say id="container".

Create the array of image name in javascript. (an array not a variable)

```
var image_array = {"ragaini2016_small.jpg", "ragaini2016.jpg", ..... so on};
```

In the javascript, write a for loop. In the loop, write the code for the table row.

```
var table_content = "";

for(var i=0; i<=3; i++) {
   table_content = '<img src = "' + image_array[i] + '" />'
}
```

image_array[i] will replace the image name from the array to the content in the loop.

Assign the "table_content" to the innerHTML of the container.

```
document.getElementById("container").innerHTML = table_content;
```